# Where are the items generated for the Magento order confirmation mail?

Tags: magento

I am running Magento 1.9 and I wonder where the items for the order confimration mail are being rendered. I checked some files and modified them, but the modifications do not reflect in the order mails item list.

In the transaction mail template, it says:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

This is the part which prints the items, but I do not find the part in the code.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but it does not help. This is not about modifying the mail template, but the items in the mail template. Those are not directly inside the template, they are generated in the code somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do modification in Order email Items from the following template files:

`template\email\order\items.phtml`

`template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml`

If you didn't find this in your current theme file, you can copy these from Base theme.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue after Magento upgrade to v1.9.4

In my case, custom theme that I use on Magento didn't include XML layout <sales_email_order_items>

To fix order items in the order confirmation email need to edit the custom theme file:
**layout/sales.xml**

And add layout section for email:

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="core/template" name="order_totals_wrapper" as="order_totals" template="email/order/totals/wrapper.phtml">
            <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
                <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                    <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_email_order_items>
```